# Passing all parameters to a git alias

Tags: git, bash

To simplify my concern, I narrowed it to the following:

I have a GIT alias defined as such:

```
cii = "!f() { git commit "$@"; }; f"
```

When I run

```
$ git cii -m "test1"
```

It works fine, but it fails with

```
$ git cii -m "test1 and test2"
error: pathspec 'and' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'test2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Any idea ?

Note that my real alias is much more complex that the above, so responding with
cii = "commit" is not an option. The point here is passing the input parameters to the function.

Comment: Why "and"? Why not just git cii -m test test1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to quote the embedded doublequotes.

```
cii = "!f() { git commit \"$@\"; }; f"
```

git will then perform standard shell expansion of `"$@"` which translates to a single word for each parameter - like `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...`

Comment: yes, looks like it. yet my real alias is still failing.. think I didn't narrow the right issue.